# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state'

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to evaluate the values that are linked to two different users. I created a different table to keep track of a user's previous experiences and their interested experiences and linked them to the user. I have a matching function that tries to find the user with the most similarities, but it gives the attribute error listed in the title.

model:

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
    prev = db.relationship('prevExp', backref='user', lazy='dynamic')
    interested = db.relationship('interestedExp', backref='user', 
                                 lazy='dynamic')
    matches = db.relationship('Match', backref='matchedTo', lazy='dynamic')

class prevExp(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    arts = db.Column(db.String(1))
    consulting = db.Column(db.String(1))
    dataScience = db.Column(db.String(1))
    education = db.Column(db.String(1))
    engineering = db.Column(db.String(1))
    finance = db.Column(db.String(1))
    government = db.Column(db.String(1))
    law = db.Column(db.String(1))
    management = db.Column(db.String(1))
    marketing = db.Column(db.String(1))
    medical = db.Column(db.String(1))
    technology = db.Column(db.String(1))
    expDescription = db.Column(db.String(400))
    userID = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))

class interestedExp(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    arts = db.Column(db.String(1))
    consulting = db.Column(db.String(1))
    dataScience = db.Column(db.String(1))
    education = db.Column(db.String(1))
    engineering = db.Column(db.String(1))
    finance = db.Column(db.String(1))
    government = db.Column(db.String(1))
    law = db.Column(db.String(1))
    management = db.Column(db.String(1))
    marketing = db.Column(db.String(1))
    medical = db.Column(db.String(1))
    technology = db.Column(db.String(1))
    userID = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))

class Match(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    person = db.Column(db.String(120))
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, index=True, default=datetime.utcnow)
    userID = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
```

routes:

```
@app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    form = RegistrationForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User(firstName=form.firstName.data, lastName=form.lastName.data,
                    username=form.username.data, email=form.email.data)
        user.set_password(form.password.data)
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Congratulations, you are now a registered user!')
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
    return render_template('register.html', form=form)

@app.route('/profile/edit/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def editProfile():
    form = ProfileForm(obj=current_user)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        previous = prevExp(user=current_user)
        previous.arts = form.prevArts.data
        previous.consulting = form.prevConsulting.data
        previous.dataScience = form.prevDataScience.data
        previous.education = form.prevEducation.data
        previous.engineering = form.prevEngineering.data
        previous.finance = form.prevFinance.data
        previous.government = form.prevGovernment.data
        previous.law = form.prevLaw.data
        previous.management = form.prevManagement.data
        previous.management = form.prevMarketing.data
        previous.medical = form.prevMedical.data
        previous.technology = form.prevTechnology.data
        previous.expDescription = form.expDescription.data
        interested = interestedExp(user=current_user)
        interested.arts = form.arts.data
        interested.consulting = form.consulting.data
        interested.dataScience = form.dataScience.data
        interested.education = form.education.data
        interested.engineering = form.engineering.data
        interested.finance = form.finance.data
        interested.government = form.government.data
        interested.law = form.law.data
        interested.management = form.management.data
        interested.marketing = form.marketing.data
        interested.medical = form.medical.data
        interested.technology = form.technology.data
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Your information has been saved!')
        return redirect(url_for('profile', username=current_user.username))
    return render_template('editProfile.html', form=form) 

@app.route('/matches')
@login_required
def matches():
    match = bestMatch()
    if match == None:
        message = "Sorry, there are no matches at this time. \
                   Please check back later!"
    else:
        message = "We've found a match for you! Check out "
    return render_template('matches.html', message=message, 
                           match=User.query.filter_by(username=match).first())
```

bestMatch function used in 'match' route:

```
def bestMatch():
    curr = []
    curr.append(current_user)
    users = set(User.query.all()) - set(curr)
    existingMatches = set(Match.query.filter_by(matchedTo=current_user))
    users -= existingMatches 
    matchScore = dict()
    for user in users:
        username, score = countSimilarities(user)
        matchScore[username] = score
    scores = matchScore.values()
    bestScore = max(scores, default=0) if max(scores, default=0) > 0 else -1
    return matchScore.get(bestScore, None)

def countSimilarities(user):
    score = 0
    if user.major == current_user.major:
        score += 1
    score += countCollege(user.college, current_user.college)
    score += countHobbies(user.hobbies, current_user.hobbies)
    score += countPrevToInterested(user)
    score += countExpDescription(user)
    return user.username, score

def countExpDescription(user):
    user = prevExp.query.filter_by(user=current_user).first().expDescription
    curr = prevExp.query.filter_by(user=user).first().expDescription
    user = set(user.split(' '))
    curr = set(curr.split(' '))
    return len(user.intersection(curr))
```

EDIT: the error:

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2309, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2295, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1741, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_login/utils.py", line 261, in decorated_view
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/gracekim/Desktop/projects/coffeechat/app/routes.py", line 96, in matches
    match = bestMatch()
  File "/Users/gracekim/Desktop/projects/coffeechat/app/matching.py", line 13, in bestMatch
    username, score = countSimilarities(user)
  File "/Users/gracekim/Desktop/projects/coffeechat/app/matching.py", line 26, in countSimilarities
    score += countExpDescription(user)
  File "/Users/gracekim/Desktop/projects/coffeechat/app/matching.py", line 52, in countExpDescription
    curr = prevExp.query.filter_by(user=user).first().expDescription
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 1792, in filter_by
    for key, value in kwargs.items()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 1792, in <listcomp>
    for key, value in kwargs.items()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/operators.py", line 365, in __eq__
    return self.operate(eq, other)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 211, in operate
    return op(self.comparator, *other, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/relationships.py", line 1093, in __eq__
    other, adapt_source=self.adapter
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/relationships.py", line 1466, in _optimized_compare
    state = attributes.instance_state(state)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state'
```

EDIT2: `__init__.py`

```
from flask import Flask
from config import Config
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_login import LoginManager

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Config)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)
login = LoginManager(app)
login.login_view = 'login'

from app import routes, models
```

Comment: No worries, my first question on here I wasn't sure what was too much or too little, easy mistake. Ok, where are you declaring and starting `app` in your flask app? That's where `__call__` is coming from. usually it's started by `app.run`

Comment: Also, [virtualenv](https://gist.github.com/pandafulmanda/730a9355e088a9970b18275cb9eadef3) can be super helpful, as you can have a python environment that doesn't require you to change the python3 environment that ships with mac

Comment: @C.Nivs I just edited the post to include my __init__.py where I declare `app`, but I'm honestly not too sure where I start it. I just run the command `flask run` in my command line

Comment: Ok, thanks, as a note, the file should (probably) be `__init__.py` in this case, note the double underscores

Answer (score 15):

Here's a really small example that reproduces the error:

```py
class Parent(Base):
    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    child = relationship('Child', backref='parent')


class Child(Base):
    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey('parent.id'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Base.metadata.drop_all(engine)
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
    parent = Parent()
    child = Child(parent=parent)
    s = Session()
    s.add(parent)
    s.commit()
    s.query(Child).filter_by(parent='a string').first()  # this line causes error
```

Which raises:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "55876558.py", line 27, in <module>
    s.query(Child).filter_by(parent='a string').first()
  File "C:\Users\peter_000\.virtualenvs\test-_0Fb_hDQ\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py", line 1689, in filter_by
    for key, value in kwargs.items()]
  File "C:\Users\peter_000\.virtualenvs\test-_0Fb_hDQ\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py", line 1689, in <listcomp>
    for key, value in kwargs.items()]
  File "C:\Users\peter_000\.virtualenvs\test-_0Fb_hDQ\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\operators.py", line 344, in __eq__
    return self.operate(eq, other)
  File "C:\Users\peter_000\.virtualenvs\test-_0Fb_hDQ\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\attributes.py", line 180, in operate
    return op(self.comparator, *other, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\peter_000\.virtualenvs\test-_0Fb_hDQ\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\relationships.py", line 1039, in __eq__
    other, adapt_source=self.adapter))
  File "C:\Users\peter_000\.virtualenvs\test-_0Fb_hDQ\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\relationships.py", line 1372, in _optimized_compare
    state = attributes.instance_state(state)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state'
```

`Child.parent` is a relationship attribute, and a good resource to help you understand how they work is [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/tutorial.html#working-with-related-objects), in the official docs. The key takeaway is that they deal with other ORM objects. So, when you query on a relationship, you need to provide an ORM object. In the above example if you replace this line: `s.query(Child).filter_by(parent='a string').first()` with this line: `s.query(Child).filter_by(parent=parent).first()`, the error goes away because `parent` is an ORM object.

In your specific case, the error comes from this line: `curr = prevExp.query.filter_by(user=user).first().expDescription`, where you pass a variable `user` to the `filter_by()` method. `user` is defined on the line above that, `user = prevExp.query.filter_by(user=current_user).first().expDescription` where you query a `prevExp` object and once it's retrieved using `first()`, you then access it's `expDescription` attribute. The column definition of `expDescription` is `expDescription = db.Column(db.String(400))`: a string. So you are passing a `str` to query the relationship attribute and creating the exact situation that the simplified example above demonstrates.

The reason for the error message `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state'`, is that every ORM object has an `_sa_instance_state` attribute. As relationship attributes are purely for representing other ORM objects, sqlalchemy assumes that the string you have passed in is an ORM object without bothering to check first (why would it?!). A string doesn't have a `_sa_instance_state` attribute, and hence the `AttributeError`.